# How to synchronize windows system time using on board embedded controller?

Tags: c++, windows, time, systemtime

I would like to create a time provider for my windows pc (Windows 7) that syncronizes time based on an embedded controller(EC) on my main board. The EC brings in time and sets specific addresses with the current time which is GPS synchronized. I have an API to the driver for the EC but need to write a time provider to be able to use this time to sync my OS. My question is how to do this? I've read through the MSDN [TimeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page but am stuck understanding the example. Does anyone on here know of a good forum or blog, etc., that has more information? I really would like more info concerning the Time Provider and can't find much.

How do I synchronize the system using this EC? Are there good sources somewhere talking about a hardware based time provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way might actually be ntp.

Write an ntp server that talks to your EC box and have windows internet time point to localhost. IIRC ntp server is a fairly trivial protocol.

Comment: Do you know if this would constitute as a stratum 1? or Stratum 0 (If that is a thing)? I assume the time delay would be minimal because it's coming from the host?

Comment: you might have just saved me days of programming. I'm marking you as the answer because you pointed me in a better direction. Thanks!